# What is the .dll Win10 stores its start menu icons in?

Tags: resources, icons, windows-10

I want to draw the icons used in Win10 start menu ('settings', 'all apps' and so on) in an app where they will mean the same. And I want to extract them instead of copying and hardcoding. But I can't find the dll where they are stored.

So far, I tried just about every dll, loaded in explorer.exe (detected by Process Explorer), opening them in the standard Windows dialog for changing icons, but to no avail. Maybe, they are stored not as ICON resources, maybe I've overlooked them.

Comment: Are you working with WinJS? Have you checked [WinJS.UI.AppBarIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770557.aspx)?

Comment: @sebagomez Very close, but not exactly what I'm looking for. No neither settings, nor explorer, nor power off. But now I think it's not an old-fashion (WinAPI) ICON resource, it's something from this WinJS.

Comment: Ok, what about the Segoe UI Symbol font?... they use many characters from there, take a look in your character map

Comment: @sebagomez Thank you, will look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These images appear to in Windows.UI.Xaml.dll (according to inspect) but I can't get them out.

Instead you will probably be better served by not relying on external icon assets and using a complete set that you can include within your app.

The settings icon appears to be from the [MDL2 font](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx) but I don't know about the others.
[image]

Do you really want to create icons which will "mean the same"? Are they going to do the same thing? (i.e. launch file explorer and control power on the PC?) If they're not controlling functionality in your app which means they do the *EXACT* same thing then using the exact same icon could be confusing. Using something similar would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Yep, it's an alternative app launcher. Thank you.